# Calling a bound script's method using the Execution API

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using `PropertiesServices` as variables, specifically **Document Properties** , in order to replace some tokens like `"{client name}"`. Since those properties are scoped to the bound script only, I'm looking for a way to modify their values from my PHP application.

Is it possible to call a bound script's function using the Execution API,  or maybe from a standalone script?  Otherwise, should I instead use the **Script Properties** instead (although the docs make me think you can't use them if the script isn't 'standalone).

Comment: Script Properties are available in bound scripts too, so the choice between property stores is up to you; Document Properties does make the most in terms of the scope... Bound scripts also have Script Id, found in the same place as for standalone scripts (File menu of Script Editor),  so I don't see any obstacle to calling their functions from Execution API. (Haven't use the API  myself, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like if the user that the Execution API is running under has permission to the doc that bound script ran by the execution api can read document properties.

Here is my test:
Create a new spreadsheet. Create a new script. Add some data using the menu from onOpen. Run executeAPI inside the script. The log successfully shows the document properties.

```
function onOpen() {
  var testMenu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("test")
  testMenu.addItem("Add some data", "addData").addToUi();
  testMenu.addItem("Preview data", "getData").addToUi();
}


function getData(){   
  var keys = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getKeys();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().clear().appendRow(keys)
}

function returnData(){
  return PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getKeys();
}


function addData(){
  var DT = new Date().toString()
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty(DT,DT);
}



function executeAPI(){
  var url = 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/'+ScriptApp.getProjectKey()+':run';

  var payload = JSON.stringify({"function": "returnData","parameters":[], "devMode": true});

  var params={method:"POST",

              headers:{Authorization: "Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}, 
              payload:payload,
              contentType:"application/json",
              muteHttpExceptions:true};
  var results = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(results) 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me it gives " Cannot call method "getKeys" of null", In your script you didn't mention/call your spreadsheet, probably you are using a built-in script (built in spreadsheet Apps Script) but when using a stand-alone Project the Documents properties store is not accessible (it makes sense) thought it can be possible that they add Documents properties after getting the spreadsheet OR implementing something like *Script.getDocumentPropertiesStore(spreadsheetId)